# Creating a sequence of columns in a data frame based on an index for loop or using plyr in r

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, plyr

I wish to create 24 hourly data frames in which each `data.frame` contains hourly demand for a product as 1 column, and the next 8 columns contain hourly temperatures. For example, for the `data.frame` for 8am, the `data.frame` will contain a column for demand at 8am, then eight columns for temperature ranging from the most current hour to the 7 past hours.  The additional complication is that for hours before 8AM i.e. "4AM", I have to get yesterday's temperatures. I am hitting my head against the wall trying to figure out how to do this with `apply` or `plyr`, or a vectorized function.

```
demand8AM Temp8AM Temp7AM Temp6AM...Temp1AM

Demand4AM Temp4AM Temp3AM Temp2AM Temp1AM Temp12AM Temp11pm(Lag) Temp10pm(Lag)
```

In my code Hours are numbers; 1 is 12AM etc.

Here is some simple code I created to create the dataset I am dealing with.

```
#Creating some Fake Data
require(plyr)
# setting up some fake data
set.seed(31)
foo <- function(myHour, myDate){
rlnorm(1, meanlog=0,sdlog=1)*(myHour) + (150*myDate) 
}
Hour <- 1:24
 Day <-1:90
dates <-seq(as.Date("2012-01-01"), as.Date("2012-3-30"), by = "day")
myData <- expand.grid( Day, Hour)
names(myData) <- c("Date","Hour")

myData$Temperature <- apply(myData, 1, function(x) foo(x[2], x[1]))
myData$Date <-dates

myData$Demand <-(rnorm(1,mean = 0, sd=1)+.75*myData$Temperature )
## ok, done with the fake data generation.
```

Comment: There are a lot of challenges here.  Most importantly, you have date and time in two separate columns when in this case, they probably should be in one column.

Comment: how large is your real data?

Comment: 24 HOURS bY 565 DAYS ABOUT 13,000 RECORDS

Comment: Keep in mind that you are ultimately replicating your data 24-fold.  It is not clear how you plan to use this output, and it is likely you could accomplish the same without replicating the data.

Comment: Ricardo: the time is hourly, but it is used as a factor. I am cutting the data by hour, so that I have 24 datasets with the same number of days. I know this part can be done with plyr and apply functions or split

Comment: Eric, it absolutely can be done.

Comment: Ricardo: Any idea where I should start looking?

Comment: The challenge, as I see it, is the alligning of the `-(1:7)` hours.  How do you suppose would be the best way to go about that?

Comment: I am playing with a for loop in which I create a dataframe within each loop that is indexed by i. So it is a list element of a list that will contain 24 dataframes. Some how i hope to be able to refer to the other dataframes in the loop and also lag some columns of the other dataframes by using Hour[[i-1]]$temperature within the for loop for hour "i" to refer to the last hour's temperature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though you could benefit from utilizing a time series.  Here's my interpretation of what you want (I used the "mean" function in rollapply), not what you asked for.  I recommend you read over the `xts` and `zoo` packages.

```
#create dummy time vector
time_index <- seq(from = as.POSIXct("2012-05-15 07:00"), 
                  to = as.POSIXct("2012-05-17 18:00"), by = "hour")

#create dummy demand and temp.C
info <- data.frame(demand = sample(1:length(time_index), replace = T), 
                   temp.C = sample (1:10))  

#turn demand + temp.C into time series
eventdata <- xts(info, order.by = time_index)

x2 <- eventdata$temp.C
for (i in 1:8) {x2 <- cbind(x2, lag(eventdata$temp.C, i))}
```

Comment: Hi Jack, this was very useful to learn but it did not answer the problem. I am reading about reshape, which I think could answer it. I will post the answer if I am able to solve it. I really appreciate the help. someone was kind enough to edit the text so maybe it will be clearer what I am looking for.